# Convert underscores to dashes with Apache mod_rewrite Kohana 2.3.4

Tags: kohana

How do I Convert underscores to dashes with Apache mod_rewrite in Kohana 2.3.4

Lets say I had www.site.com/purchase_item

and I want it to be

www.site.com/purchase-item

From an SEO perspective, the later is prefered

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways you can solve this, the easiest is probably entirely with mod_rewrite rules. You can do everything you want to do with two rewrite rules:

1. redirect all requests with underscore to dash
2. rewrite all requests with dash back to underscore for the backend (kohana) to process easily.

I didn't test this but I think it should work:

```
# redirect all requests with underscore to dash (this will do three dashes at a time, hopefully results in only one redirect for the client)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ([^_]*)_([^_]*)
RewriteCond %1-%3 ([^_]*)(_([^_]*))?
RewriteCond %1-%3 ([^_]*)(_([^_]*))?
RewriteCond %1-%3 ([^_]*)-*$
RewriteRule .* %1 [L,R=301,QSA]

# rewrite all requests with dash back to underscore
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ([^-]*)-([^-]*)
RewriteCond %1_%3 ([^-]*)(-([^-]*))?
RewriteCond %1_%3 ([^-]*)(-([^-]*))?
RewriteCond %1_%3 ([^-]*)_*$
RewriteRule .* %1 [L]
```